# Had been vs was

Tags: grammaticality

Now this is confusing... I wanna know the difference between the following sentences:

> If you **were** there, I would see you.
>
> If you **had been** there, I would have seen you.

What's the difference between 'were' and 'had been'? And could we use 'were' instead of 'had been' in the 2nd sentence?

Comment: The first one is effectively a "subjunctive" usage where the *"I would see you"* part strongly implies either a "present tense irrealis" (you're not there right now - but if you *were*, I'd see you), **OR** a *future* situation (if you were to be there at some point in the future, I would see you then).

Comment: Both are subjunctive; the first is past (or were) subjunctive and could be described, in ESL terms, as second conditional, which states a present counterfactual as @FumbleFingers above has said; the second is the "pluperfect/past perfect" (emphasis on the quotes) subjunctive and, in ESL, is called third conditional, which states a past counterfactual (something happened in the past and if it hadn't, x would be the result).

Comment: You will find this Wiki article helpful. It is on the question of 'conditional sentences', i.e. ones that begin with 'if'. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [ell.se] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenario #1 - It is the present (now) and you are not here:

*"If you were there, I would see you."*

Scenario #2 - In the past and you were not there

*"If you had been there, I would have seen you."*

Scenario #3 - In the future

*"If you are here tomorrow, I will see you."*

In the first two cases, are counter-factual

Comment: Not sure it's that simple: Scenario 1: If you were there tomorrow I would see you (future). Scenario 2: If you'd been in the line up tomorrow I would have seen you (future). Scenario 3 If you're there tomorrow, I'll see you. (future)

Comment: @Araucaria I'm struggling to think of a context in which your scenario 2 would see use, if it's even a valid construction.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like the first two scenarios are subjunctive, but the last one is conditional. 
"If you were there" is an English subjunctive mood. The indicative mood for the pronoun I is was, but since it's subjunctive we use were.

Answer (score 0):

If you are there, I will see you. (Future main clause, subject to the action in dependent clause)

If you were there, I would see you. Here, both the actions didn't happen. It's like, I couldn't meet you because you were not there.

If you had been there, I would have seen/ met you. Similar to the second example; subjunctive; as both the actions didn't take place.

The difference in the second and third will be clear when used in reported speech. E.g., 
Direct speech: He said to Joe, "If you are at home, I shall meet you.
Reported speech: He said to Joe that if Joe was at home, he would meet him.

Direct speech: He said, "As she was sleeping, I did not disturb her."
Reported speech: He said as she had been sleeping, he hadn't disturbed her."